# pytest - How to patch a method to avoid database call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mocking, pytest, pytest-django

For the purpose of learning I am trying to write a test that patches Django's `authenticate` function in order to avoid having to hit the database. The code I have written does not work and I do not understand why. I have scoured the web but am finding a lot of what I read confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Django, DRF, pytest, pytest-django, and pytest-mock.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

def test_authenticate(mocker, user_factory):
    user = user_factory.build()

    mocker.patch('django.contrib.auth.authenticate', return_value=user)

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.get('/')

    data = {
        'username': user.email,
        'password': 'testpassword',
    }

    assert user == authenticate(request=request, **data)
```

In the code above `user_factory` comes from `conftest.py` and we can assume it works as expected.

The error I receive is:

```
E       Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

Again, I want to avoid having to mark the test for db access. Instead, I want to be able to mock `authenticate` and control its return value.

Comment: Try to just import `import django.contrib.auth` then mock `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` and also call it as such in the assertion `user == django.contrib.auth.authenticate(stuff)`

Comment: Yes, that worked. And it put me on the right track for my real, more complex scenario. Thank you. Would you like to post and answer for me to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule #1 for patching: Your first guess what you should be patching is always wrong.
Rule #2 for patching: Don't patch where something *IS* but patch where something *WILL* be looked up during execution.

You imported `authenticate` and added it to the namespace as `authenticate`. 
When patching the patcher imported `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` to the namespace and then mocked it.
Later you call `authenticate`, the original version that you had imported at the beginning - not the mocked version that the patcher has imported for you.

By importing just `django.contrib.auth` and then patching `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`, the patcher 'sneaks' in its mocked `authenticate` into `django.contrib.auth`.
If you then do the assertion with `user == django.contrib.auth.authenticate`, python will look for `authenticate` in `django.contrib.auth` and will find the mock instead.

Classic patching mystery:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch